# Calculating BER for BPSK in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ber

I wrote this code for comparing manually calculated BER and theoretical BER graphically.

The manually calculated BER (err) is always 1x1 value and I want it as a range of values corresponding to SNR values.

I also replaced this line:

```
err=error+1;
```

with this line:

```
err(k)=error+1;
```

and still not working.

Can anybody solve this problem?

Here is the code:

```
N=100;                               % number of bits

SNR=0:1:10;                          % Different values for SNR

err=zeros(1:length(SNR));            % Initilizing calculated error for 
                                     % different SNR values

for k=1:1:length(SNR)

    N0(k)=10^(-SNR(k)/10);            % Calculating the noise level

    s=randn(1,N)>.5;                 % generating random number of logic bits
                                     % with equal probability 0.5    
    s=2*s-1;                         % Generating BPSK sequence between logic 1 , -1

                                     % Generating real random noise with SD of 0.1
    n = sqrt(N0(k)/2)*(randn(1,N) + j*randn(1,N));   

    r=s+n;                           % Noisy signal 

    rd=zeros(1,N);                   % Initializing Detected signal

        for i=1:1:N

            if(r(i)>0)              % Comparing detected signal against a threshold
                rd(i)=1;
            else
                rd(i)=0;         
            end
        end

    error=0;

        for j=1:1:N                 % calculating BER

            if(abs(rd(j)-s(j))==1)
                error=error+1;        
            end
        end


        err=error+1;                   % calculated error for this value of SNR

end

th_err=.5*erfc(sqrt(10.^(SNR/10)));   % Theoretical BER

semilogy(SNR,th_err,'*r');grid on;title('Bit error rate for BPSK');xlabel('Eb/N0');ylabel('Theoritical BER');
```

Comment: Start by not using [`error`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/error.html) as a variable name, it is a key in-built function name. Then if you use `err(k) = ___` there is no way you result in `err` being 1x1 if `length(SNR)` is greater than 1. Finally, the `% calculating BER` loop is a bit redundant, nothing changes inside the loop so you can just test your condition (which should probably be `abs(abs(rd(j)-s(j)) - 1) < 1e-10` to avoid floating point issues) once and set `err(k) = N`.

Comment: Dear Wolfie, thanks for your help. but how then I plot manually-calculated error against SNR as long as it is 1x1 value ?

Comment: That sentence isn't very clear...

Comment: Dear Wolfie, 

I finally spotted the error. It should be zeros(1,N) instead of zeros(1:N)